# Android Studio newbie - How to read a file and give an output?

Tags: android

I've been working on this project for a few days and I can't figure out why it keeps crashing. The project is to take a file which is located in the assets folder with a bunch of doubles in it (using an input from the user containing the file name), find their cosine, and display the result for the user to see. Here's my MainActivity class:

```
package com.example.brandon.lab1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new               StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void cosAndDisplay(View view)
        throws IOException {
    EditText et;
    TextView tv;
    int numOfItems;
    String fileName;
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_main);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_infile);

    fileName = (et.getText().toString());
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    Scanner fsc = new Scanner(assetManager.open(fileName));
    ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    while (fsc.hasNextDouble()) {
        String[] line = fsc.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (String s : line) {
            nums.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
        }
    }
    fsc.close();
    numOfItems = nums.size();
    cos_it(nums, numOfItems);
    ArrayList<String> numList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x = 0; x < numOfItems; x++) {
        numList.add(nums.get(x).toString());
    }

    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    for (int y = 0; y < numOfItems; y++) {
        tv.setText(formatter.format(numList.get(y)));
    }
}



public static void cos_it(ArrayList<Double> a, int num_items) {
    for(int x=0; x<=num_items; x++) {
        a.set(x, Math.cos(a.get(x)));
    }
}
```

}

this is the crash report:

```
--------- beginning of crash
10-10 16:02:25.649 3009-3009/com.example.brandon.lab1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.brandon.lab1, PID: 3009
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at com.example.brandon.lab1.MainActivity.cos_it(MainActivity.java:104)
    at com.example.brandon.lab1.MainActivity.cosAndDisplay(MainActivity.java:88)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
10-10 16:02:28.687 3009-3009/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3009 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Share the log for more details.

Comment: just added it..

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the logcat, you got a

> Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

from the method **cos_it** wherein the input parameter for the ArrayList is of size 0, meaning that it does not any item inside it.

You need to debug if the required ArrayList is being populated properly or not.